# Dynamic Array in C for memory mapping

Tags: c, linux, memory

I am currently trying to allocate separate chunks of memory using `malloc` in order not to allocate a huge amount of contiguous block of memory at one go but by allocating separate memory allocations. Having said that, in order to keep track of the allocated memory I am trying to keep  each pointer in a dynamic array to hold each reference to the memory allocated. Is this the best approach for handling large memory allocations or  there is a better how this can be handled?

Comment: As it turns out, dynamic allocation is best done in big chunks to avoid fragmentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let malloc and friends handle this for you. That's what they are designed to do, build on that instead of wasting effort redoing what experts provide as part of your programming environment.

Comment: So ideally, I should go directly for a malloc even for allocating a large file's contents read from a server machine. Am I right?

Comment: @Bran for that there are other tools, like mapping the file to memory